# Maven: use install-file goal with altDeploymentRepository

Tags: maven, maven-2, repository, maven-3, maven-install-plugin

Just a simple question here.

I've tried:

```
mvn install:install-file 
-DaltDeploymentRepository=../releases 
-Dfile=gcm-server.jar
-Dsources=gcm-server-sources.jar
-DgroupId=com.google.android.gcm
-DartifactId=gcm-server
-Dversion=1.0.2
-DpomFile=gcm.pom
-Dpackaging=jar
-DcreateChecksum=true
```

But i got the following:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Installing /home/sebastien/Bureau/gcm-server-repository/deployer/gcm-server.jar to /home/sebastien/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gcm/gcm-server/1.0.2/gcm-server-1.0.2.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/sebastien/Bureau/gcm-server-repository/deployer/gcm.pom to /home/sebastien/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gcm/gcm-server/1.0.2/gcm-server-1.0.2.pom
[INFO] Installing /home/sebastien/Bureau/gcm-server-repository/deployer/gcm-server-sources.jar to /home/sebastien/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gcm/gcm-server/1.0.2/gcm-server-1.0.2-sources.jar
```

Is there a way to install file to an alternative local maven repository?
I've checked the `install:install-file` but it doesn't mention the installation of the files to an alternative repository. Is it even possible, or i will need to move the files myself from one repository to another?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `-Dmaven.repo.local=path-to-alternate-repo`

e.g.

```
-Dmaven.repo.local=/tmp/myrepo
```

Comment: Thanks. It works nice but it also copy other files to this repository (maven plugin jars) while i would like to only have the jars i want in that folder

Comment: @SebastienLorber.  Yes, since you are referring to a `local maven repository`.  You can't have maven put only selected jars therein.